# Does Android Studio have a note section?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-plugin

I don't know enough about Android Studios and was wondering if there was a note section for Android Studio. My goal is whenever I come back to my project I can read my notes on the last thing I did and what I need to work on next.

This is my first time creating an Android App and using Android Studio Application.

I do know there is a task and context tool that I could use but is there an offline version? Where I don't have to link it to YouTask, GitHub, or Jira, and etc? Just my own personal notes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of a notes feature specifically bit Android Studio does support custom Todos: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-todo.html

If you use these you can comment
`// todo fix this bug`
and it will show up in your todo list at the bottom of the IDE.

[image]

Comment: Oh! Very cool! Thank you @banjoe! Ill work with what is provided!